# how to compile pam_radius on mac 10.7 and/or 10.8

Tags: c

How to compile pam_radius_auth (http://freeradius.org/pam_radius_auth/) on a modern mac osx 10.7 or 10.8 system with macports=2.1.2 xcode-4.5.2 gcc47.

I get many errors including, but not limited to:

pam_radius_auth.c:358:23: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct timezone'
     struct timezone tz;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is fairly old (2007 for the latest modifications).  Of itself, that need not be a problem.

The 'struct timezone' problem with [`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) is fixed by including `#include <sys/time.h>` per POSIX.

The problems with `pam_get_item()` etc not being declared are fixed by commenting out the `#ifdef sun` and `#endif` protection around `#include <security/pam_appl.h>`.

```
pam_radius_auth.c:886:24: warning: passing 'int *' to parameter of type 'socklen_t *' (aka 'unsigned int *') converts
      between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
                                     0, &saremote, &salen)) < 0) {
                                                   ^~~~~~
/usr/include/sys/socket.h:615:25: note: passing argument to parameter here
                socklen_t * __restrict) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(recvfrom);
```

That can be fixed by changing:

```
int salen, total_length;
```

to:

```
int total_length;
socklen_t salen;
```

The problem:

```
pam_radius_auth.c:1104:12: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'const char *' from
      'const char **'dereference with * [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
      user = userinfo;
```

That can be fixed by changing the line to:

```
user = *userinfo;
```

The problem:

```
md5.c:176:27: warning: 'memset' call operates on objects of type 'struct MD5Context' while the size is based on a
      different type 'struct MD5Context *' [-Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess]
    memset(ctx, 0, sizeof(ctx));        /* In case it's sensitive */
           ~~~            ^~~
md5.c:176:27: note: did you mean to dereference the argument to 'sizeof' (and multiply it by the number of elements)?
    memset(ctx, 0, sizeof(ctx));        /* In case it's sensitive */
```

can be fixed by changing the line to:

```
    memset(ctx, 0, sizeof(*ctx));        /* In case it's sensitive */
```

(and that's an impressive warning!)

With those changes in place:

```
$ make
cc -Wall -fPIC -c pam_radius_auth.c -o pam_radius_auth.o
cc -Wall -fPIC   -c -o md5.o md5.c
ld -Bshareable pam_radius_auth.o md5.o -lpam -o pam_radius_auth.so
ld: unknown option: -Bshareable
make: *** [pam_radius_auth.so] Error 1
$
```

The makefile notes that more modern versions of GCC support `-shared` (but guesses that `ld -Bshareable` works most places).  So, let's try:

```
$ cc -shared -o pam_radius_auth.so *.o -lpam
$
```

---

#### Patch

```
--- pam_radius-1.3.17/Makefile  2007-03-25 21:22:11.000000000 -0700
+++ pam_radius-1.3.17.fixed/Makefile    2012-12-07 20:26:17.000000000 -0800
@@ -55,7 +55,8 @@
 #  gcc -shared pam_radius_auth.o md5.o -lpam -lc -o pam_radius_auth.so
 #
 pam_radius_auth.so: pam_radius_auth.o md5.o
-   ld -Bshareable pam_radius_auth.o md5.o -lpam -o pam_radius_auth.so
+   gcc -shared pam_radius_auth.o md5.o -lpam -lc -o pam_radius_auth.so
+#  ld -Bshareable pam_radius_auth.o md5.o -lpam -o pam_radius_auth.so

 ######################################################################
 #
--- pam_radius-1.3.17/md5.c 2007-03-25 21:21:07.000000000 -0700
+++ pam_radius-1.3.17.fixed/md5.c   2012-12-07 20:11:17.000000000 -0800
@@ -173,7 +173,8 @@
     MD5Transform(ctx->buf, (uint32_t *) ctx->in);
     byteReverse((unsigned char *) ctx->buf, 4);
     memcpy(digest, ctx->buf, 16);
-    memset(ctx, 0, sizeof(ctx));   /* In case it's sensitive */
+    //memset(ctx, 0, sizeof(ctx)); /* In case it's sensitive */
+    memset(ctx, 0, sizeof(*ctx));  /* In case it's sensitive */
 }

 #ifndef ASM_MD5
--- pam_radius-1.3.17/pam_radius_auth.c 2007-03-26 02:36:13.000000000 -0700
+++ pam_radius-1.3.17.fixed/pam_radius_auth.c   2012-12-07 20:13:21.000000000 -0800
@@ -57,9 +57,9 @@
 #include <limits.h>
 #include <errno.h>

-#ifdef sun
+//#ifdef sun
 #include <security/pam_appl.h>
-#endif
+//#endif
 #include <security/pam_modules.h>

 #include "pam_radius_auth.h"
@@ -766,7 +766,9 @@
 talk_radius(radius_conf_t *conf, AUTH_HDR *request, AUTH_HDR *response,
             char *password, char *old_password, int tries)
 {
-  int salen, total_length;
+  //int salen, total_length;
+  socklen_t salen;
+  int total_length;
   fd_set set;
   struct timeval tv;
   time_t now, end;
@@ -1099,7 +1101,7 @@
     DPRINT(LOG_DEBUG, "Got PAM_RUSER name %s", userinfo);

     if (!strcmp("root", user)) {
-      user = userinfo;
+      user = *userinfo;
       DPRINT(LOG_DEBUG, "Username now %s from ruser", user);
     } else {
       DPRINT(LOG_DEBUG, "Skipping ruser for non-root auth");
--- pam_radius-1.3.17/pam_radius_auth.h 2007-03-25 22:35:31.000000000 -0700
+++ pam_radius-1.3.17.fixed/pam_radius_auth.h   2012-12-07 20:07:34.000000000 -0800
@@ -15,6 +15,7 @@
 #include <stdarg.h>
 #include <utmp.h>
 #include <time.h>
+#include <sys/time.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <netdb.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
```

---

Save patch as `pam_radius.patch`.  Extract source into sub-directory `pam_radius-1.3.17`.  Apply patch using:

```
$ cd pam_radius-1.3.17
$ patch -p1 --dry-run -i ../pam_radius.patch --verbose
Hmm...  Looks like a unified diff to me...
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- pam_radius-1.3.17/Makefile 2007-03-25 21:22:11.000000000 -0700
|+++ pam_radius-1.3.17.fixed/Makefile   2012-12-07 20:26:17.000000000 -0800
--------------------------
Patching file Makefile using Plan A...
Hunk #1 succeeded at 55.
Hmm...  The next patch looks like a unified diff to me...
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- pam_radius-1.3.17/md5.c    2007-03-25 21:21:07.000000000 -0700
|+++ pam_radius-1.3.17.fixed/md5.c  2012-12-07 20:11:17.000000000 -0800
--------------------------
Patching file md5.c using Plan A...
Hunk #1 succeeded at 173.
Hmm...  The next patch looks like a unified diff to me...
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- pam_radius-1.3.17/pam_radius_auth.c    2007-03-26 02:36:13.000000000 -0700
|+++ pam_radius-1.3.17.fixed/pam_radius_auth.c  2012-12-07 20:13:21.000000000 -0800
--------------------------
Patching file pam_radius_auth.c using Plan A...
Hunk #1 succeeded at 57.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 766.
Hunk #3 succeeded at 1101.
Hmm...  The next patch looks like a unified diff to me...
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- pam_radius-1.3.17/pam_radius_auth.h    2007-03-25 22:35:31.000000000 -0700
|+++ pam_radius-1.3.17.fixed/pam_radius_auth.h  2012-12-07 20:07:34.000000000 -0800
--------------------------
Patching file pam_radius_auth.h using Plan A...
Hunk #1 succeeded at 15.
done
$
```

That's a dry-run; remove that option to actually apply the patch.

Tested on Mac OS X 10.7.5 using:

```
$ cc --version
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.65) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix
$
```

When compiled with GCC 4.7.1, I get one residual warning:

```
$ make CC=gcc
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c pam_radius_auth.c -o pam_radius_auth.o
pam_radius_auth.c: In function ‘pam_private_session’:
pam_radius_auth.c:1290:7: warning: variable ‘ctrl’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
gcc -Wall -fPIC   -c -o md5.o md5.c
gcc -shared pam_radius_auth.o md5.o -lpam -lc -o pam_radius_auth.so
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.7.1
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$
```

#### Warning

I only got the code to compile; I did not test it!